# How come Python thinks my dictionary is a list? I get a TypeError when trying to change a value

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

So I've got this little script that adds songs to an Rdio playlist. It mostly works just fine. First it reads a CSV and creates a list of dictionaries, with each dictionary containing attributes for the track. Here's the code that does that:

```
csv_tracks = []
f = open('./testing_tracks.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    csv_tracks.append({'artist':row[1], 'title':row[0], 'status':row[2]})
f.close
```

The 'status' value is a string of either 0 or 1, just to signal whether the track has already been added to the playlist (so I don't keep re-adding the same track over and over).

The problem appears later in the script, where I run a loop to search for each track on Rdio, and add it to a playlist if found. Here's the code:

```
for track in csv_tracks:
    if track['status'] == '0':
        if find_track(track) != None:
            key = find_track(track)
            add_to_playlist(key)
            track['status'] = '1'
            print 'Adding %s by %s to the playlist' % (track['title'],track['artist'])
```

I get a TypeError. Here's the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 76, in <module>
    if track['status'] == '0':
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

The truly odd thing is that the script seems to work mostly fine. For tracks with status == '0', it searches for them and adds them to the playlist and then logs a message as per above ('Adding...to the playlist'). The only thing that doesn't work is track['status'] is not changed to '1' when a track is added. And I get the error.

I don't really understand why Python seems to think that my dictionary is a list and can only accept integer indices. Any help?

DISCLAIMER: I am a beginner. Be gentle if I'm doing something terribly stupid :)

Comment: Check the code in between. Do any lines you omitted use the name `csv_track`?

Comment: Add in a `print(csv_tracks)` and see what it is.

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but to close a file, you need to *call* `f.close()`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Or better yet, use [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Comment: @Lattyware That solved it. I did the print statement and it mostly gave me what I expected - a list of dictionary items - but the last entry had somehow become a dictionary within another list. That was screwing things up. Thanks for your trouble-shooting help!

Comment: I bet you inadvertently added a list to csv_tracks somewhere. The program 'mostly works' until the iteration gets to this list.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `csv.DictReader` it allows you to access elements by name. The default `csv.reader` returns each record as a list.